# can't access to wildfly administration console with admin user

Tags: jboss, wildfly

i had installed jboss Developer Studio and i added a wildfly server 9 , it starts normally but i can't connect to the administration console with the user : admin password : admin

Comment: Did you add the user with the add-user script?

Comment: Is it necessary ? I thaught that jboss has a default user called admin with password admin

Comment: Yes, i think, but you can easily check the management users.

Comment: it worked thanks :)

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the management users under: JBOSS_HOME\standalone\configuration\mgmt-users.properties. If the file is empty, then you should add a new management user with the script add-user (BOSS_HOME\bin\add-user) [like](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/add-user+utility)

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/add-user+utility This links is no accessible.